# Xcode 7 (7A218 ) search in file behaviour change

Tags: ios, xcode, editor

Xcode 7 (7A218) changed the default search in file preference. 
In case that there are more than one occurrence of the searched text the next item will not move to the beginning of the file. It used to be circular, but now it is just one way.
Is there any way I can alter this to switch back to circular?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit Find options -> Mark as Wrap